# Is there a way to limit my app to iOS devices with great than 4" inch screens?

Tags: ios, iphone

iPhone SE (1st Generation), which was discontinued over 3 years ago, can run iOS 15. But it's the ONLY device in Apple's lineup with a 4" screen that can run anything higher than iOS 12.

Is there anything I can put in the Info.plist to ensure that my app only runs on devices greater than 4"?

Comment: Why don’t you want to adapt to SE ? The latest 12 mini and 13 mini have screen which are not that bigger compared to SE.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do what you want to do. I realize that means supporting 320px (logical) screen width, and it's the only model left at that res.

So, I'd recommend supporting that screen size by running it in the simulator, and working it out.